# Magento 1 - categories not updating. New categories added not showing

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

We have a strange problem with our store (will call it Store A) where any category we add/edit is not reflected on the front-end. Here is is what we have checked and ensured:

- The Store's Root category is correct under stores
- We emptied the cache and rebuilt the indexes

**Our Setup**

We have 5 stores running under the same installation and the problem is just with Store A. *Strangely, when we assign the root category of Store A to any other store, it shows up fine.*

Anyone else experience a similar problem? Any help guideline will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you experimented turning the catalog flat data on and off (in configuration->catalog) and then reindexing and resetting cache?

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't help. One point worth mentioning is that this is only on certain categories. Even the meta titles don't get changed on the front-end. We even disabled the cache but still the same.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue with category info not updating and found that this was the case only when the store view was set to all store views. Select the appropriate store view, then make the category edits and all is good.

Comment: While programmatically update the category details, it's reflecting in front-end and default store view, but the updated values are not reflecting in all store view.